# How to combine specific items in an array of objects depending on the key: value of each object whilst maintaining the order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like below. Each object has permanent key 'type' and depending on the 'type', new keys are added.

So if `type: 'text'`, we have a new key 'text'.

If `type: 'notText'`, we have a new key 'attrs'.

```
arrayOfObj = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "="
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": " "
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "S"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "O"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Something",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "H"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "E"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Y"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Other",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "="
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "T"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "O"
    },
]
```

The objects are in order, so depending on the 'type' of each item AND the order, then I need to combine them like so:

```
arrayOfObj = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "= SO"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Something",
        }
    }
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "HEY"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Other",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "=TO"
    },
]
```

In summary, whenever 'type' = 'text' then combine every single object with type 'text' that are together. If the next object has type 'notText', then leave it alone until the next item with 'type' = 'text'. Then combine those.

I've asked a previous question that was similar to this with the working answer

```js
let arrayOfObj = [{
    "type": "text",
    "text": "="
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "S"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "O"
  },
  {
    "type": "notText",
    "attrs": {
      "id": 20,
      "data": "Something",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "H"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "E"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Y"
  },
  {
    "type": "notText",
    "attrs": {
      "id": 20,
      "data": "Other",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "="
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "T"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "O"
  },
];
let newThing = arrayOfObj.reduce(
  (textKey, typeKey) => {
    if (typeKey.type === "text") {
      textKey[0].text += typeKey.text;
    } else {
      textKey.push({
        type: typeKey.type,
        attrs: typeKey.attrs
      });
    }
    return textKey;
  }, [{
    type: "text",
    text: ""
  }]
);
console.log(newThing);
```

However it combines all instances where 'type' = 'text' regardless or order or other objects with 'type' = 'notText'.

Would anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: what if there are 2 objects i.e `notText` comes together then what should happen?

Comment: Is the array always start by ```type: "text,```?

Comment: Do you mean what if there are two objects in order with type 'notText'? In that case they would be left alone with their order maintained, only those with 'type' = 'text' need to be changed.

Comment: @ikhvjs Each object in the array will always have a 'type' key and if 'type': 'text' then it would always be in this format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `Array.reduce` again, starting with an empty array.

If the last item in the array we build up is of type 'text', append the current item, otherwise just add it to the array:

```js
const arrayOfObj = [ { "type": "text", "text": "=" }, { "type": "text", "text": " " }, { "type": "text", "text": "S" }, { "type": "text", "text": "O" }, { "type": "notText", "attrs": { "id": 20, "data": "Something", } }, { "type": "text", "text": "H" }, { "type": "text", "text": "E" }, { "type": "text", "text": "Y" }, { "type": "notText", "attrs": { "id": 20, "data": "Other", } }, { "type": "text", "text": "=" }, { "type": "text", "text": "T" }, { "type": "text", "text": "O" }, ]
    
const result = arrayOfObj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // If the last item was of type 'text' _and_ the current item is too.. append the text
    if (acc[acc.length-1]?.type === 'text' && curr.type === 'text') { 
        acc[acc.length-1].text += curr.text;
    } else {
        // Either current or last item in array was not type 'text' 
        acc.push(curr)
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log('Result:', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do that:

```js
arrayOfObj = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "="
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": " "
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "S"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "O"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Something",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "H"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "E"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Y"
    },
    {
        "type": "notText",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Other",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "="
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "T"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "O"
    },
]

let output = [];

arrayOfObj.forEach(x => {
  if (
    x.type == 'notText' ||
    output.length == 0 ||
    output[output.length - 1].type == 'notText'
  ) {
    output.push(x)
  } else {
    output[output.length - 1].text += x.text
  }
})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here

```js
const arrayOfObj = [
  { type: "text", text: "=" },
  { type: "text", text: " " },
  { type: "text", text: "S" },
  { type: "text", text: "O" },
  {
    type: "notText",
    attrs: { id: 20, data: "Something" },
  },
  { type: "text", text: "H" },
  { type: "text", text: "E" },
  { type: "text", text: "Y" },
  {
    type: "notText",
    attrs: { id: 20, data: "Other" },
  },
  { type: "text", text: "=" },
  { type: "text", text: "T" },
  { type: "text", text: "O" },
];

const result = arrayOfObj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { type, ...props } = curr;
  const last = acc[acc.length - 1];
  if (!last || last.type !== "text" || last.type !== type) acc.push(curr);
  else last.text = last.text + props.text;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: upvote for reusing `last` but downvote for not using curlys (if you want to be terse use ternary).